# How do I calculate the difference in days, months and years between two dates with leap years?

Tags: c

I'm requesting the user to enter two dates (day, month and year).

Using the `time.h` header, I'm storing it in a `struct tm` variable like following (let's say date1):

```
date1.tm_mday = day;
date1.tm_mon = month;
date1.tm_year = year - 1900;
date1.tm_hour = 0;
date1.tm_min = 0;
date1.tm_sec = 0;
date1.tm_isdst = 0;
```

The second date (date2) is the same above but with "date2" instead of "date1" (two structures).

Next, I did the mktime of date1 and date2 to calculate the seconds of both dates:

```
date1TimeT = mktime(&date1);
date2TimeT = mktime(&date2);
```

Following, I checked whether the date1 is bigger than date2, so I placed:

```
if(date1TimeT > date2TimeT)
    finalDateTimeT = date1TimeT - date2TimeT;
else
    finalDateTimeT = date2TimeT - date1TimeT;
```

Now to calculate the days, months and years that have passed through this two dates:

```
totalDays = (int) finalDateTimeT / 86400;
remainingYears = totalDays / 365;
remainingMonths = (totalDays - remainingYears * 365) / 30;
remainingDays = (totalDays - remainingYears * 365 - remainingMonths * 30);
```

However, this is not 100% accurate, as this does not take care of the leap years (those who are divisible by 4).

Is there a safer way to calculate this? Keeping in mind the leap years.

Comment: `time.h` is not a library.  Headers are not libraries.

Comment: My bad, I'm used to call it library by other programming languages.

Comment: You don't have to calculate years and months.  You start with those values so just subtract.  Then you only have to worry about leap year in one year.

Comment: `tm_mon` is months since January so between 0 and 11 you need to do a minus one

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  How many days are there between Sept 2, 1752, and Sept 14, 1752?  Or Oct 1 and Oct 30 in 1582?  Do you want to take into account leap seconds?

Comment: @WilliamPursell If 0 years have passed (for example), then it will show "0 years, 0 months and 12 days" in that scenario.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to calculate months because months are not all the same length and it depends where you start. The same is true for years (to a lesser extent). Weeks would make sense. For years and months and days, you could calculate upper and lower bounds, but it is a bit fiddly.

Comment: @r0dr1 Run "cal 9 1752" and see what you get.

Comment: @dbush Holy .sh (funny joke). I don't know why this happens, this is the first time I see this.

Comment: @r0dr1 That was when the switch from Julian to Gregorian dates happened, so there was a correction.

Comment: @r0dr1 I think you're missing my point.  Sep 14 is one day after Sep 2 in 1752 (depending on the calendar you use).  The question is inherently ambiguous, and requires a great deal of outside information.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You're right, but how can it be done then? If there's this change in the calendar, how could you find a way to calculate it?

Comment: If there are 20 days left in the start month and the end date is the 20th of a month, and there are M calendar months in between, how many months and days is M months and 40 days? The task makes no sense. Unlike say, an hour always comprising 60 minutes, there isn't a fixed number of days in a month.

Comment: I think the 1752 problem is not relevant. The OP uses time_t for the dates and this starts in 1970. For the solution you should walk from start date to end date and monitor month changes. What should be the result of `2022-03-01 - 2022-01-31` or `2005-02-28 - 2004-02-29`?

Comment: You might want to use `difftime` instead of simple arithmatic, for portability.

Comment: @user5329483: 1752 might be outside of the range but it's simply a dramatic instance of a repeated problem. Countries and regions do decide to switch time zones, including the decision to move to the other side of the international date line, thereby creating a discontinuity. (Daylight Savings/Summer time transitions only lose or add hours, not days, although it can still create ambiguities if the hour didn't exist or existed twice in one of the endpoint dates, especially in places which change at midnight.)

Comment: @rici: Nobody hinders us to send UTC instead of localtime into the procedure. With this we get rid of time zone changes, like DST.

Comment: @user5329483: Sure. But that changes the meaning of the interval measure. (Personally, I don't think "what is the difference in years and months" is precisely definable. But presumably whoever asked the question has some definition in mind.)

Answer (score 2):

> How do I calculate the difference in days, months and years between two dates?

There are two totally different ways to do this.  The more popular one is the way you've already tried: First convert both dates to some common, monotonic timebase, such as a Unix-style `time_t` value. Then subtract.  This gives you a simple difference in, in this case, seconds.  You can divide by 86400 to get days, but it's hard to see how to convert to months or years.

The reason it's hard is that our familiar year/month/day/hour/minute/second system of date/timekeeping is a [*mixed base*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) scheme, and it's worse than that, in that different months have different numbers of days.  There's no single constant days-per-month value you can divide by, the way there is for, say, inches-per-foot (or even hours-per-day).

And then time zones, daylight saving time, leap years, and leap seconds can make things even *more* complicated.

But in fact, those complications are one reason that the convert-to-monotonic-timebase technique is so popular, because it cuts through most of that complexity rather nicely.  Assuming that library functions like `mktime()` and `localtime()` have been implemented properly, they take care of *all* the nasty details of time zones, daylight saving time, and leap years.  Just about the only thing left for you to do is to make sure you use them correctly.

Using them correctly involves:

- making sure to encode the `tm_year` and `tm_mon` fields of `struct tm` correctly (this is easy to get wrong, and in fact your posted code makes one of the common mistakes, forgetting that `tm_mon` is 0-based)
- making sure to set `tm_isdst` to -1 if you want `mktime` to figure out whether DST applied for the date/time in question or not
- setting tm_hour to 12 (not 0) if you're only interested in dates, not times (this helps to avoid certain anomalies that can crop up near DST transitions, although this probably wouldn't matter for your problem), and
- when converting to days, remembering to *round*, not truncate, when dividing by 86400, since you may see an effective 23- or 25-hour day length if you're straddling a DST transition.

Leap years are generally not a problem when using this technique, and I'm not sure what you meant when you said that it was "not 100% accurate" because it "does not take care of the leap years". `mktime` and `localtime` understand leap years perfectly, and will allow you to compute a proper difference (in seconds) between two dates which straddle the February/March transition, in both leap and non-leap years.  It's true that you won't get an accurate number of years if you just divide by the constant 365, but that's no worse than the way you'll often get the wrong number of months if you divide by a constant 30.

So if you've converted to a monotonic number of seconds, the answer to the question of how you convert to years, months, and days is: you don't.  It's an impossible, ill-defined problem.  You'll have to settle for presenting an answer in terms of just days, or perhaps divide by 7 to get weeks and days.  (Or you can present a decidedly approximate answer after dividing by an average number of days per month, like 30.43.)

Now, just about everyone would agree that, informally at least, the difference between, say, February 5 and March 7 is "one month and two days".  Notice that this is equally true in leap and non-leap years.  If you want to implement this more "informal" or "human-centric" algorithm in a C program, you certainly can, although it's not going to involve `mktime` or `localtime`.  Instead, it's going to be an implementation of mixed-base arithmetic, with a complication due to the fact that the number of days per month is not constant.

Suppose we want to find the difference between April 5, 2021 and June 10, 2022.  That will look like

```
  year    month   day
  2022    6       10
- 2021    4       5
  ----    --      --
     1    2       5
```

The answer is "One year, two months, and five days".  This problem was simple, because we didn't have to borrow.

Here's a harder one: what's the difference between January 25,
2020 and March 5, 2020?  That looks like

```
  year    month   day
  2020    3       5
- 2020    1       25
  ----    --      --
  ????    ??      ??
```

What are we supposed to do with this?  The first date is clearly greater than the second, but of course 5 is less than 20. Informally, from January 25 to February 25 is one month, and then it's a few more days until March 5, but that "few more days" hits the worst case, because it straddles the end of February, so we have to worry about whether it's a leap year or not.

The way to work the problem is probably like this:

```
  year    month   day
  2020    2       34
- 2020    1       25
  ----    --      --
  0       1       9
```

Here I have borrowed 1 from the month's column, and added it in to the day's column.  Since 2020 was a leap year, there were 29 days in February, so the adjusted days number after the borrow is 5+29=34.

You might have to implement a similar borrow from the year's to the month's column, although that's easier, because the number of months per year is always 12.  (That is, I'm pretty sure you will *not* have to worry about leap years at that point in the algorithm.)

I'm out of time for this too-long answer, so I'm not going to write any C code to do this mixed-base arithmetic, but with this prose outline I think you should be able to implement it straightforwardly enough.

Footnote 1: The algorithm I've presented isn't quite complete.  It will not handle, for example, the interval from January 31 to March 1 properly.  It's not necessarily obvious how to handle that rather problematic case, but the answer is probably to add the possibility of looping and borrowing twice, as @chux shows in his answer (see comment "Might loop twice").

Footnote 2: Remember that in our [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), the leap-year determination is [*not* a simple test for divisibility by 4](http://c-faq.com/misc/leapyear.html).

Footnote 3: For completeness and for anyone who might be curious, I'll say a little more about leap seconds.  Unlike leap years, leap seconds are *not* just automatically taken care of for you by `mktime` and `localtime`.  In fact, handling leap seconds properly is more or less impossible under the conventional `mktime`/`localtime` scheme, for the simple reason that the Unix `time_t` representation denies the existence of leap seconds altogether.  Due to the presence of leap seconds, UTC is *not* the uniform, continuous, monotonic time scale that `time_t` assumes. Handling leap seconds properly requires thinking pretty carefully about how you want them to affect your addition and subtraction algorithms, and it requires using some data type other than `time_t`.

Footnote 4. Best not to worry at all about the anomalies that happened in 1752 (or whenever your country changed over to the Gregorian calendar). :-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea to go through the delta days is a bad one. Once you pass the month boundary you are in trouble. Each month has 28..31 days. In your original post you assume every month to have 30 days.

In order not to loose relationship with the month's lengths we have to work directly with day/month/year. We can combine month+year in one variable as **every** year has 12 months, like the expression `month+year*12`. Here my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void PrintDelta (int StartYear, int StartMonth, int StartDay, int EndYear, int EndMonth, int EndDay)
{
    //Month and Day are 1-based
    int Start_MonthYear = StartYear * 12 + StartMonth-1;
    int   End_MonthYear =   EndYear * 12 +   EndMonth-1;
    int Delta_MonthYear = End_MonthYear-Start_MonthYear;
    int Delta_Days      = EndDay-StartDay;

    if (Delta_Days < 0)
    {
        //Like Jan 31st --> Feb 1st
        //remove one month from Delta_MonthYear and add one month to Delta_Days
        if (0)
        { //old buggy code used month before end date
           static const int MonthDays[2][12]=
           {
               //MonthDays[][0] is the number of days in the month BEFORE January!!
               //12 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 <--- month
               { 31,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30}, //non-leap year
               { 31,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30}  //leap year
           };
           Delta_Days += MonthDays[(EndYear & 3) ? 0 : 1][EndMonth-1];
        }
        else
        {  //better code uses month from start date
           static const int MonthDays[2][12]=
           {
              { 31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}, //non-leap year
              { 31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}  //leap year
           };
           Delta_Days += MonthDays[(StartYear & 3) ? 0 : 1][StartMonth-1];
        }
        Delta_MonthYear--;
    }
    printf("Timespan from %d-%02d-%02d to %d-%02d-%02d is %d year(s), %d month(s), %d day(s)\n",
           StartYear, StartMonth, StartDay,
           EndYear,     EndMonth,   EndDay,
           Delta_MonthYear/12, Delta_MonthYear%12, Delta_Days
          );
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PrintDelta(2000,2,28,  2001,3,1);  //1yr 1day, including Feb 29th
    PrintDelta(2001,2,28,  2002,3,1);  //1yr 1day, no Feb 29th
    PrintDelta(2022,1,11,  2022,1,21); //10 days
    PrintDelta(2022,1,31,  2022,2,1);  //one day
    PrintDelta(2022,1,31,  2022,3,1);  //1 month 1 day
}
```

Comment: Nice job.  Now try `PrintDelta(2022,1,31, 2022,3,1);` :-(

Comment: @SteveSummit: Good point. Changed my answer to use days of starting month instead. But this changes the result for 1st test case `PrintDelta(2000,2,28,  2001,3,1);` What should be the correct result? 2 days (brings us to 2000-03-01) plus one year? Or one year (brings us to 2001-02-28) plus one day? The latter approach asking for trouble if you start at Feb 29th.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what the "correct" result should be!  (There may not be one.) Also I suspect switching to the starting month is probably not an improvement.  The fundamental problem is that we're trying to fill in the blank in the sentence "One month after January 31 is February 31, and then it's ___ more days until March 1", but that sentence has a big, obvious problem before you even fill in the blank!

Comment: I think the solution is as in chux's answer, where his code says "might loop twice".

Answer (score 1):

Subtract days, then months, then years.  The only challenging issue is how to *borrow* from *months*

---

Some illustrative sample code below -simplifications exist.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_leap_year(int year) {
  // Leave this for OP
}

// year: Gregorian calender
// mont: 0 = Dec, 1 = Jan, ... 12 = Dec
static int days_per_month(int year, int month) {
  static const char dpm[] = {31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
  if (month == 2 && is_leap_year(year)) {
    return 29;
  }
  return dpm[month];
}

typedef struct {
  int year, month, day;
} ymd_type;

// *a - *b
// Assume: a and b elements are already in their preferred ranges and a >= b.
ymd_type date_subtract(const struct tm *a, const struct tm *b) {
  ymd_type ymd = {a->tm_year + 1900, a->tm_mon + 1, a->tm_mday};
  ymd.day -= b->tm_mday;
  while (ymd.day < 0) {  // Might loop twice
    ymd.month--;
    ymd.day += days_per_month(ymd.year, ymd.month);
  }
  ymd.month -= b->tm_mon + 1;
  if (ymd.month < 0) {
    ymd.year--;
    ymd.month += 12;  // 12 months per year
  }
  ymd.year -= b->tm_year + 1900;
  return ymd;
}

int test_ymd(int y1, int m1, int d1, int y0, int m0, int d0) {
  const struct tm t1 = {.tm_year = y1 - 1900, .tm_mon = m1 - 1, .tm_mday = d1};
  const struct tm t0 = {.tm_year = y0 - 1900, .tm_mon = m0 - 1, .tm_mday = d0};
  ymd_type ymd = date_subtract(&t1, &t0);
  printf(" %4d/%2d/%2d - %4d/%2d/%2d = %2dy %2dm %2dd\n", y1, m1, d1, y0, m0,
      d0, ymd.year, ymd.month, ymd.day);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample

```
int main() {
  test_ymd(2022, 2, 17, 2020, 1, 1);
  test_ymd(2022, 3, 1, 2020, 12, 31);
  test_ymd(2022, 3, 1, 2022, 1, 31);
  test_ymd(2020, 3, 1, 2020, 1, 31);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 2022/ 2/17 - 2020/ 1/ 1 =  2y  1m 16d
 2022/ 3/ 1 - 2020/12/31 =  1y  1m 29d
 2022/ 3/ 1 - 2022/ 1/31 =  0y  0m 29d
 2020/ 3/ 1 - 2020/ 1/31 =  0y  0m 30d
```

To Do:

- Handle cases when dates are in the opposite order.
- Handle cases when the date is not in the primary rage.
- Handle extreme case like when year is near `INT_MAX`.